# jquery referring issues with css' type selector

Tags: jquery, css, types, jquery-selectors

In the following snippet of code I want to click the top box to toggle color, but jQuery is not properly referring the object. Any help will be greatly appreciated. The box is tagged with table with id='tst'. The box itself is a td cell, which is a type selector of an id selector 'tst' (defined in css). jQuery is somehow not referring to the object. See the code below. The bottom box is just for reference...

```
<html><head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tst td").click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('green');
});
});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
table#tst {border:solid 1px;}
#tst td 
{background-color: red;}

.green {background-color:green;}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<p>Click the top box to toggle color between red and green.<br> Bottom box is for    reference.</p>
<table id="tst"><tr><td width=50 height=50></td></tr></table>
<br>
<table border=1><tr><td width=50 height=50></td></tr></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`#tsd td` is a more specific selector than `.green`.
Therefore, adding the `green` class doesn't actually change the color.

Comment: Yup, you should do `td.green { background-color: green; }`

Comment: @elclanrs: That won't help; the ID is still more specific.

Comment: You're right. `!important` will do the trick then. But well, not the most elegant solution...

Comment: Or without using `!important`: `#tsd td.green { background-color: green; }`

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/CdeNA/ - working.